# Neural network design using matlab

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I want to get the weights between the last hidden layer and output layer from the deep neural network designed using matlab codes.

I have tried with net.LW but it is returning the weights between 2 hidden layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use net.LW to pass in two indices to get the weights between two layers.

```
net.LW{i,j}
```

Use numel(net.layers) to get the number of layers. This will be the index of the output layer. One less is the index of the last hidden layer.

```
j = numel(net.layers)
i = numel(net.layers) - 1

net.LW{i,j}
```

You can update with variables for your app.

MATLAB Answers Reference: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/499607-set-a-specific-weight-for-a-connection-in-neural-networks